# Check extension of multiple file

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my project, I want upload one or multiple image files. I check the extension in the PhP, but I want check in jquery before send the form to the PhP, for more security, but i have no idea about work with a array of files in jQuery. Sorry my bad english.

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" id="formAdicionarProduto" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div class="form-group">
  <input type="file" id="arquivos-imagens" name="arquivos[]" multiple>
 </div>
 <button type="submit" id="enviar" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('#enviar').click(function(){ }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a loop in files property of input object to get some information of each file:

```
<input type="file" multiple id="myInput" />

var myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');
myInput.onchange = _ => {
    for (var i = 0; i < myInput.files.length; i++) {
        var file = myInput.files[i];

        console.log(file.name); // file_XYZ.xlsx
        console.log(file); // Other info: size, type, etc.
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery, you could do:

```
$('#arquivos-imagens').on('change', function() {
    for (let file of this.files) {
      const fileExtension = file.name.substring(file.name.length - 3); // Get only extension.
      console.log(fileExtension);
    }
});
```